# Angular Materials Cards Layout

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-card

I'm using Angular Mat Card and I have a button that create new cards in the database every time I click the button but the new card display right at the bottom of existing card with out any gap between the two so if you guys can help me figure it out how to make the gap/margins it'll be awesome. Thanks

[This is what it look like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMWy0.jpg)

[This is what I want to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1PGD.jpg)

```css
 .clickable {
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 .mat-chip {
     background-color: #DFDFDF;
     text-align: left;
     font: Regular 16px/21px Roboto;
     letter-spacing: 0.29px;
     color: #000000DE;
     opacity: 1;
     border-radius: 18px;
     opacity: 1;
 }
 .mat-card {

     margin-left: -10px;
     padding: 0;
     margin-bottom: 20px;;
     width: 350px;
     height: auto;
     cursor: pointer;
     
   
   }
 .chipMargin{

     margin-left: 5%;
     margin-right: 5%;
 }
 .mat-chip-list {
   display: table-row;
   flex-direction: column;
 }
@media screen and (min-width:768px)
{

.divider {
   height: 90%; 
   position: absolute; 
    left: 900px;
    right: 830px;
    top: 40px; 
 }
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 950px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;

    
}
.column2 {
    width: 730px;
    float: right;
    right: 70px;
    position: absolute;
  


}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  .inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<h2 style="font-size: 1.5em; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 20px; color: white;">Home</h2>
<div matSubheader>
    <span style="font-size: 1.2em; margin-left: 20px; color: white;">My Workspaces</span>
    <button mat-stroked-button color="accent" matTooltip="New Workspace" (click)="newWorkspaceClick()">
        <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> New
    </button>
</div>

  <div class="column">
    <mat-nav-list>
        <div class="row">
                <div>
                  <mat-card class="example-card"><a mat-list-item routerLink="workspace/{{ws.guid}}" *ngFor="let ws of workspaces" >
                      <mat-icon matListIcon color
                          matTooltip="{{ws.type == WorkspaceType.user ? 'User Workspace' : 'Group Workspace'}}">
                          
                      </mat-icon>
                      <span matLine>Stack One</span>
                      <span matLine class="hint"></span>
                    </a>
  
                  </mat-card>
                  
                </div>       
        </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </div>
  
  <mat-divider [vertical]="true" class="divider"></mat-divider>
  <div style="position: absolute;font-size: 1.2em; right: 630px;top: 80px; color: white;"> Recently Edited Charts</div>
  <div class="column2">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <div class="row">
              <div>
          
              </div>       
      </div>
  </mat-nav-list>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add margin-bottom CSS property to your card like so:

```
.mat-card:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

EDIT:

I took a closer look to your code and I noticed that you're not creating cards, you're creating list items inside of the card. Your `ngFor` directive is placed on the `a` tag. Place the `ngFor` directive on the card or if you want to create list items add the following code:

```
.mat-list-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but sadly it's still not working. Not sure why it's still stacking/attached together even I added that. hmm

Comment: @aasenomad I've edited my answer. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I'm curious! Why are you using this in your component?: <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

Comment: It work! woo hoo!. thank you so much for the help.  I just use the meta tag just to play around with different devices screen width. I already delete it.